# Laravel SwiftMailer Different Domains

Tags: php, email, smtp

I have an web application that is supposed to send emails with bounce controlling and analytics integration and i have an mail code like this:

```
Mail::send('emails.newsletter', [
    'unsub_code' => $this->contact[$i][3], 
    'emailTo' => $this->contact[$i][1], 
    'emailFrom' => $this->email, 
    'user' => $this->contact[$i][0], 
    'UUID' => $this->contact[$i][2], 
    'campaignName' => $this->campaign->name, 
    'campaignId' => $this->campaign->id, 
    'header' => $header,
    'body' => utf8_encode(html_entity_decode($this->campaign->body)), 
    'footer' => html_entity_decode($this->campaign->footer)], 
    function ($m) use ($i) {
        $m->from('email@mydomain.ss', 'AAB');
        $m->to($this->contact[$i][1])->subject($this->campaign->subject);
        $headers = $m->getHeaders();
        $headers->addPathHeader('Return-Path', 'bounce@mydomain.something');
        $headers->addTextHeader('uuid', $this->contact[$i][2]);
        $headers->addTextHeader('cpName', $this->campaign->name);
        $headers->addTextHeader('cpId', $this->campaign->id);
});
```

My problem is that i want to send  emails from other@otherdomain.xx but maintain the bounce@mydomain.ss but that gives me an error because the other@otherdomain isnt the same as the env one.

Comment: The error is in Portuguese but i basicly says this : "expected code 250 but got code 550 , with message <the sender domain(other@otherdomain.xx) must be the same has the SMTP authenticated domain(email@mydomain.ss). The email was considered spoofed"

Comment: That error has nothing to do with PHP or Laravel. That's your _mail server_ refusing to send mail on behalf of another user.

Comment: so how would i go about solving this?

Comment: Use a mail server that doesn't restricting the sending address. It'll need to be a third-party SMTP provider like SendGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well like **jszobody** pointed in the comments this is actually a problem with my hosting blocking me from sending email from other domains, this will actually be solved by purchasing another service from them which enables me to do so.

Since i'm developing the application i don't want to use a third-party SMTP provider which is also a good solution cost wise.